# How to create a 3D model of a leaf in Matlab

Tags: matlab, graphics, 3d, 3d-modelling

I want to create a 3D model of a tree's leaves in Matlab. Can Matlab do it? Any tutorial that will be useful for me?

Thank your very much.

Comment: look into fractals, something like: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29537-generation-of-3d-fractal-trees

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want make leaf procedural, nice article about it is from Bodo Habenicht:  Die analytische Form der Blätter, Quedlinburg, 1895..

If you want whole plants, check [Practical Procedural Modeling of Plants](http://www.td-grafik.de/artic/talk20030122/overview.html)..